Why does importing a module cause my kernel to die? (Jupyter)
I'm trying to run some code in Jupyter Lab/Notebook (I have tried both) and every time it gets to the 'import speasy as spz' command, I get an error telling me that my kernel appears to have died and is restarting.
I have created a new code with only the command 'import speasy', which still doesn't work so I know this is the issue.
I have already tried a number of common issues that don't work including making sure I have enough memory.
I am using Python 3.12.4 and speasy 1.4.0.
Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

It seems like it is a pretty demanding package to import. You can see it take quite a bit of time to be ready after triggering that import if you go to [the Speasy repo](https://github.com/SciQLop/speasy and click on the 'launch binder' badge and then run that import statement when the session starts. (Alternatively, click here to launch.) That means it has some heavy lifting it is doing. Are you able to use it remotely? In those temporary sessions served by the MyBinder service, the CompleteDemo.ipynb works well.
